# NSDictionary to NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have a `NSDictionary` which looks like:

```
{
"Item1" = 2.4;
"Item2" = 5.5;
"Item3" = 15.6;
}
```

To use this `NSDictionary` Items in a Table View i have to transfer it to a `NSArray`, am i right?

So i try:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [myDict objectForKey:@"items"];

for (id item in dict) {
    [_myArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:item]];
}
```

But _myArray keeps empty? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Leaving aside the technical issues with the code you posted, you asked this:

> To use this Dictionary Items in a Table View i have to transfer it to a NSArray, am i right?

The answer to which is: not necessarily. There's nothing intrinsic to the machinery of `UITableView`, `UITableViewDataSource`, or `UITableViewDelegate` that means that your data *has to* be in an array. You will need to implement various methods to tell the system how many rows are in your table, and what data appears in each row. Many people find it much more natural and efficient to answer those questions with an ordered data structure like an array. But there's no *requirement* that you do so. If you can write the code to implement those methods with the dictionary you started with, feel free!

Comment: I know it's an old post, but sir, you guessed my thoughts!

Answer (score 224):

```
NSArray * values = [dictionary allValues];
```

Comment: Hey,
i want to add Objects to the Array, not only the values.

Comment: If you read the documentation, `allValues` returns every object that would be returned by invoking `objectForKey:` for every key in the dictionary.

Comment: If you want to add more objects, you'll need to make this an NSMutableArray like so:


`NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictionary allValues]];`

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? The other answer didn't even attempt to answer the question, just said "You don't HAVE to! Good Luck!"

Comment: This answer does not give you array of key value pairs but instead array of just values. I guess this might be the reason it is not accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 44):

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];
```

Comment: These two will allow you to split the keys and values of the NSDictionary into two separate NSArrays. Very helpful.

Comment: Be aware that `allKeys` and `allValues` not necessarily generate the same order! So the first item in "keys" might not be the key to the first item in "values".

Answer (score 4):

You can create an array of all the objects inside the dictionary and then use it as a datasource for the TableView.

```
NSArray *aValuesArray = [yourDict allValues];
```

Answer (score 3):

**Code Snippet1:**

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray * values = [dictionary allValues];
[array addObject:values];
```

**Code Snippet2:** If you want to add further

```
[array addObject:value1];
[array addObject:value2];
[array addObject:value3];
```

And so on

Also you can store key values of dictionary to array

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that could be happening here.

Is the dictionary you have listed the `myDict`?  If so, then you don't have an object with a key of `@"items"`, and the `dict` variable will be nil.  You need to iterate through `myDict` directly.

Another thing to check is if `_myArray` is a valid instance of an NSMutableArray.  If it's nil, the `addObject:` method will silently fail.

And a final thing to check is that the objects inside your dictionary are properly encased in NSNumbers (or some other non-primitive type).

Comment: No, myDict is not the example shown above, it should show you that i have a NSDictionary of NSDictionarys.

How can i check if my objects are NSNumbers?

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I misuse "addObject".

I want to addObjects of NSDictionarys to my Array! So i have to do it in another way!

Answer (score 1):

To get all objects in a dictionary, you can also use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` like so:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
[yourDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [yourArray addObject:obj];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize your NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray  *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is actually used to add values to the `dictionary` and `through` the data to an `Array` According to the `Key`.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDictionary *dicto = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hello",@"StackOverFlow",@"Key1",@"StackExchange",@"Key2", nil];
NSLog(@"The dictonary is = %@", dicto);
arr = [dicto valueForKey:@"Key1"];
NSLog(@"The array is = %@", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (NSArray *)getArrayListFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictMain paramName:(NSString *)paramName
{
    if([dictMain isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        if ([dictMain objectForKey:paramName])
        {
            if ([[dictMain objectForKey:paramName] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            {
                NSArray *dataArray = [dictMain objectForKey:paramName];

                return dataArray;
            }
        }
    }
    return [[NSArray alloc] init];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4:

```
let dict = ["Item1":2.4, "Item2": 5.4, "Item3" : 6.5]

let array = Array(dict.values)
```