# Copying NSDictionary to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a variable declared as `NSDictionary`. How can I copy it to an `extern const NSArray` variable? For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *selectedItem = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[selectedItem setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:targetCustomCell.checked]     
                 forKey:@"checked"];
```

Comment: Check     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274022/nsdictionary-to-nsarray

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`allKeys` returns an `NSArray` containing all the keys. `allValues` returns an `NSArray` containing all the values.

```
NSArray *keys = [myDict allKeys];
NSArray *values = [myDict allValues];
```