# get contents of NSMutableDictionary into NSMutable array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

How to get  contents of NSMutableDictionary into NSMutable array?

I am trying following but its crashing

```
for(int i=0; i< [dict count] ; i++){

  [array_listToDisplay addObject:[dict objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"NAMES"];
}
```

Please help

Comment: dictionary consist of objects and keys which are array if you successfully try to gets keys and objects may be you will be able to map NSMutableDictionary into NsMutableArray

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274022/nsdictionary-to-nsarray

Comment: Did you look at the console to find out *why* it's crashing? I'll bet you get a message there that says `dict` does not respond to the selector `-objectAtIndex:`. Dictionaries are not arrays, and NSDictionary doesn't provide a `-objectAtIndex:` method.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. The code you've got is completely wrong. I see you've got a `dict` variable and an `array_listToDisplay` variable. Which objects in `dict` do you want to add to the array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want the dictionary's keys, or the dictionary's values?

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict allKeys]];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict allValues]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add all the objects in the dictionary to the array, you just do this:

```
[array_listToDisplay addObjectsFromArray:[dict allValues]];
```